# rendering controller in symfony gives exeption error timeout

Tags: php, symfony

I am using **Symfony3.2**. I would like to solve an error that took to me a lot of time. Here is my code **twig.html**:

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="helloModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="helloModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="helloModalLabel">Add hello</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
            {{ render(controller('AppBundle:Bye:editHello', {'id': '1'})) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My function **editHelloAction** in the controller is like this:

```
function editHelloAction($id, $Request)
{
   // Do an error: instantiate unfound object.
   $unfound = new Unfound();
   return new Response();
}
```

The first time I got this error was because I did a mistake in writing a thing but there I did an error inside my function. The **profiler** and **logs** in Symfony don't give me anything. They say this:

```
Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded
```

They should told me **Unfound** is not an entity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your request should be write `Request $request`, not `$Request`, usualy, we write it has the first parameter of the method.

<strike>Your response shouldn't be empty</strike> There is no point about an empty response : [documentation here](http://api.symfony.com/3.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.html#method___construct)

Comment: @ysd By "$Request", do you mean "Request $request" ? I don't think it's valid in symfony to do $Request.

Comment: Yes it's Request $request @Kall

Comment: @ysd The problem with the render controller is that it call the workflow of symfony again. You have 2 instances of Symfony. That's really heavy. Can you try to do it like this : {% render 'AppBundle:Bye:editHello' with { 'id': 1 } %}. If it's not necessary to have a method, try an include insted, it's faster.

Comment: @ysd The problem is that your Error is a native PHP error... The usual explenation is an infinit loop, but I don't see one on your code, so try also to change your php.ini : max_execution_time = 360, max_input_time = 120, memory_limit = 256M

Comment: I understand the error and I resolve it. The error was that I was using an unfound object, but the compiler was not telling me that, that's what I don't understand.

Comment: Great ! Keep enjoy coding ^^.

Comment: do you have an idea why the compiler did not tell me that I am using unfound object and it is telling me maximum execution time? @Drogo

Comment: As I say, make a render controller is initiating twice Symfony, so maybe the execution time to finde the method, find the error and log the error was too long, so it say timeout before the right error. But we can't be sure...